# What are some 'Realistic' ideas for side-quests?

Tags: campaign-development, story, campaign

Okay, to start off by "Realistic", I don't mean stern, and lifeless. I mean within realms of reason, and not high-fantasy stuff.

So, our group is playing a campaign, and there's no over-arching story yet. (Using modules is not something we can do) So, basically, we're going from side-quest, to side-quest. Thus far, a lot of them have been very out there. Stuff like saving a city's treasury, and burning buildings down (long story). Stuff that would make me feel more important, but we kinda skipped over the smaller stuff to start out with.

The only kinda stuff I can think of is taking out bandit camps/stolen forts, and fighting thugs in the city. But, those are a bit-samey. So, what are some other good ideas? I'm not against including magic, or fantasy elements, I just want a bit more narrative progression. IMO we shouldn't be fighting stuff like Dragons/Demons at like LV 3. (Not to say we've done that exactly) Any ideas are welcome, thanks for your time.

Comment: Is it really a side quest if it's the party's main goal?

Comment: This is entirely too broad of a question, a forum would probably be a better place to workshop plot ideas.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what setting or game you are playing?

Answer (score 2):

## The Big List

[Here](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/blueroom/plots.htm) is S. John Ross's big List of RPG Plots. I find this list to be very helpful, especially when I'm not sure what to do for the next session. Your side quests can be bonus objectives for every main quest, or the subplot within a plot. You can find S. John Ross's suggestions under the *tips and tricks* section. These plots work in a variety of games, with differing levels of fantasy from high fantasy to hard sci-fi. The plots can be side-quests or full on campaigns. It is a great resource.

I specifically wish to direct you to the non-combat plots. "Quest for the Sparkly Hoozits," "Most Peculiar, Momma," and "Blackmail" are some non-combat plots to investigate. You find those plots in a lot of other games, too.

## Narrative Progression

It sounds like you really want some major plot, not side quests. If you can have a mastermind or organization which was the reasons for a lot of your side quests, you'll see some plot progression there. If you're a player, thinking about why your character is doing things can lead to plot progression. Also, your character can try to figure out why these side-quests are needed.

Of course, your DM may be building up to something. There is only one way to know; play more!